# how maven decide what typeof project build and how to control multiple modules in single maven project?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

OK this question is not relating coding issue and I want best resource for learn following two thing can you please help me for that please .

1. I want to know how maven decide what type of project he build when we run build the output will be .war or .jar file but how it decide this is war project or jar project
2. and I also need reference for learn how to manage more than one maven project in single project that mean when I build parent project all the sub projects will include in it

so those are my questions

Comment: 1) It is specified in the POM file.  Example `<packaging>war</packaging>`.  2) That question is off-topic.

Comment: For your second part this is called a multi module build which handles exactly those cases...

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, Maven decides what packaging to use by looking at the `<package>` tag.
As an example

```
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>my-example</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

This will package the project as a `war` file.

**EDIT : THIS IS A WRONG WAY**
For your second question, may be what you are looking for is `profile` in maven. As an example

```
   <profiles>
      <profile>
        <id>my-service</id>
        <modules>
            <module>../my-service-one</module>
            <module>../my-service-two</module>
        </modules>
      </profile>
  </profile>
```

In the above snippet `my-project-one` refers to the `POM` file of this "my-project-one" module. When you are building the `my-service` , its associated modules `my-project-one` and `my-project-two` gets build.

**ACCEPTED WAY**
You can use the `Multi-Module Project` structure in maven to achieve your second objective.

Comment: Never use profiles for modules https://blog.soebes.de/blog/2013/11/09/why-is-it-bad-to-activate-slash-deactive-modules-by-profiles-in-maven/

Comment: @khmarbaise Thanks for pointing that out. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Just another hint would be having `<module>../..</module>` in your pom this is a smell as well cause it's an indicator that your directory structure does not represents your real project structure....